# C# Abstract class two methods same name but with different inputs

Tags: c#

```
public abstract class A
{


}

public class B:A
{
     public bool method(int n1, int n2)
    {
       //condition returns true or false
    }
}

public class C:A
{
     public bool method(int n1, int n2, out int res, out string label)
    {
       //condition returns true or false and also gives out res, label
    }
}
```

I have an abstract class that has same method name but with different inputs and in different inherited classes.
I have another class file, where i have to use these two methods in different cases, How can i add them in abstract class A with proper access modifiers.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean, you want `public int add(int n1, int n2);` only in B and `public int add(int n1, int n2, int n3);` only in C?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. All of your classes have problems: 1) Your abstract class declares methods with no bodies, but doesn't declare them as abstract. 2) Each of your concrete classes only overrides a single method. 3) Your concrete class methods are missing the `override` modifier.

Comment: I m sorry, i havent described my problem clearly....

Comment: After your edit your abstract class contains no methods at all, so it's still not at all clear what your question is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suspect what you are looking for is:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract int add(int n1, int n2);
    public abstract int add(int n1, int n2, int n3);
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    public override int add(int n1, int n2)
    {
        return (n1 + n2);
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override int add(int n1, int n2, int n3)
    {
        return (n1 + n2 + n3);
    }
}
```

Ultimately, C (which is **not** declared as `abstract`) needs to provide an implementation for both `add` variants (which it does by implementing one of them 'directly' and one of them via B).

*If you want C to **not** inherit from B, but only provide one implementation - alas that is not possible if C is not `abstract`.*

Comment: @NickBull That is a common misunderstanding, although if you try this for yourself at https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ih64c you can see it works fine. The key to understand here is that `C` **does** override (i.e. implement) both of them - one directly, and one through its base class. So, why does B compile? It compiles because `abstract` classes do **not** need to implement both of them (or any of them in fact).